# Replace data between special character

Tags: java, file, text, replace

My text file has a pattern and it's just like the following:

```
1;Mary Yeah;John Freeman;(12)3456-7890;iammary@gmail.com

2;Ash Wilson;One Two Three;(99)1111-2222;lorddragon@hotmail.com

3;Xin Zhao;Street Address 55;(11)0101-0202;lolyourface@gmail.com

4;My Name;My Address;My Phone;myemail@mail.com
```

I want to be able to type the line number, the type of data I want to replace(e-mail, phone, name), and the string I want to replace them with. The program overwrites the text.

How could I code this in Java?

Comment: Seems like an entire app, rather than a question. Read on what needs to be done and try to do it yourself.

Comment: If you code it in Java you should use / read into Scanner, Files.readAllLines(path), Files.write(path, lines, options) and the answer of Tim.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of how to find a given row based on the line number depends on many things, most importantly it depends on code you haven't shown us.  But as for what you can do once you have found a given line, you may try the following:

```
String line = "2;Ash Wilson;One Two Three;(99)1111-2222;lorddragon@hotmail.com";
String[] parts = line.split(";");
parts[4] = "some.address@mail.com";     // to change the email
// now join back to a single line
line = String.join(";", Arrays.asList(parts));
```

### Demo